# how can I use a declared variable inside SWIFTUI body view

Tags: swift, swiftui

I cannot use my declared variable inside body view. If I use

```
 .fill(colorWheel["darkOrange"])
```

inside Ellipse, then it breaks, but if I change to `.fill(Color.orange)`, which is a system color, then it's fine.

```
struct ContentView: View {
//our color palette
var colorWheel : [String: Color] = [
    "darkOrange"    : Color.init(hex: "F1615D"),
    "mediumOrange"  : Color.init(hex: "FF8761"),
    "darkYellow"    : Color.init(hex: "FFC575"),
    "lightYellow"   : Color.init(hex: "F1FAC6"),
    "brightAqua"    : Color.init(hex: "79E6E3"),
    "lightAqua"     : Color.init(hex: "a8e6cf"),
    "limeGreen"     : Color.init(hex: "dcedc1"),
    "brightPeach"   : Color.init(hex: "ff8b94"),
    "mediumPeach"   : Color.init(hex: "ffaaa5"),
    "lightPeach"    : Color.init(hex: "ffd3b6"),
]

var body: some View {
    ZStack{
        VStack {
            AnimatedContentView()
            Spacer()

            ZStack {
                Ellipse()
                    .fill(colorWheel["darkOrange"])
                .frame(width: 300, height: 150)

                Text("Glad you are here.\n Animate this")
                    .animation(.spring())
                    .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                    .font(.system(size: 28))
            }
            .rotationEffect(.degrees(-24))

        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.black.opacity(0.7))
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    } //end zStack
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
.fill(self.colorWheel["darkOrange"] ?? Color.green)
```

Replace Color.green to your default color whatever you want to apply if there is no color.